# Is there a way to write async setUp and tearDown functions in unittest.dart?

Tags: dart

I need to start an external process for some tests, and it requires some async calls. Right now I can start and stop the process in each test, but under a failure I really need a proper `tearDown`.

Comment: I came across a need for this as well in doc-code-merge. I'm creating a temp directory in my tests, and I need to delete it after the test completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to return Futures from setUp and tearDown was added a couple of weeks back, and the ability to return a Future from a test function was committed today.

Answer (score 0):

Justin, what you're asking for doesn't exist. I see that you've created this bug (http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7670&q=async%20setup&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary#makechanges). That's the best we can do for now.